# Can display fragment but map cannot

Tags: java, android, google-maps

In my xml i have this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/contactusscene"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ContactUsScene" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In code like this

```
mMap = mapfm.getMap();
mMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);

UiSettings settings = mMap.getUiSettings();
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
            .newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition(new LatLng(10.23454,
                    123.5543534), 13.5f, 30f, 112.5f)));
    mMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
    settings.setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
    settings.setCompassEnabled(true);
    settings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    settings.setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
    settings.setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);
    settings.setTiltGesturesEnabled(true);
    settings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    settings.setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
```

In the log, its keep running this and cannot display location and map. It only in silver color.

```
05-25 20:50:33.689: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(11275): Enter: GetBackBuffer(), surface: 0x3ef488, bufid: 0
05-25 20:50:33.689: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(11275): Return: GetBackBuffer(), TRUE
05-25 20:50:33.709: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(11275): Enter: GetBackBuffer(), surface: 0x3ef488, bufid: 1
05-25 20:50:33.709: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(11275): Return: GetBackBuffer(), TRUE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user this way:

in your layout.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

you activity:

```
public class showMaps extends AbstractMapActivity {

    private GoogleMap map;   


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (readyToGo()) {
            setContentView(R.layout.showmaps);

            SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);    
            map = mapFrag.getMap();   
        }
    }

}
```

Here is [AbstractMapActivity.java](https://github.com/dhaval0122/DJ-Android-/blob/master/getDirectionGoogleMap/src/com/DJAndroid/getDirection/AbstractMapActivity.java) add this file in your code:

Here is [fullcode](https://github.com/dhaval0122/DJ-Android-) use if needed.

make sure you have added all required permissions, openGL, MAP API key(Your own key).

for more detail [android-manifest](https://github.com/dhaval0122/DJ-Android-/blob/master/getDirectionGoogleMap/AndroidManifest.xml) for map.

Comment: I want the map half page only, that why i not set it to parent

Comment: see here i have aded two fragments. you have to just add them vertically if you want to show map in only half page http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2013/04/android-using-fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

Add below permissions in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<permission 
    android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" 
    android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
<uses-permission 
    android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission 
    android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
```

inside `<application>` tag add below code. replace **API Key** with your api key.

```
  <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value=" API Key"/>
```

**extends** your Activity from `FragmentActivity`.

Then use below code.

```
FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

SupportMapFragment mySupportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) myFragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

GoogleMap myMap = mySupportMapFragment.getMap();
```

Then do your stuffs with `myMap` object.

Comment: I had added but still the same

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
        if(status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
                    // what you want to do
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

then you have to add this:

```
if (googleMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);       

            if (googleMap != null) {

                UiSettings settings = googleMap.getUiSettings();

            settings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
            settings.setCompassEnabled(true);
            settings.setTiltGesturesEnabled(false);

             settings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

            }
        }
```

Note:

```
SupportMapFragment mMap;
GoogleMap googleMap;
```

hope that helps you.